# Using NGSX with the router plugin module

Tags: ngxs

Is there any sample app available that shows ngsx with the ngsx router plugin with fully working 'time travel' debug capabilities with action handlers that subscribes to action classes like 'RouterNavigation'. I have looked through all the applications in the community page (https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/community/projects#media) but didn't find an example of that.